# Working around a Error#1007 in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on AS3 and i'm getting a Error 1007 for... well, don't really know. This is the code in question (some functions and variables are in spanish, sorry about that)

```
public class Prueba extends Escena 
{

    public function Prueba() 
    {
        super();
        //HERE IS WHERE IT EXPLODES
        AgregarLinea(
            "Prueba 1",
            new Nerea());
        AgregarLinea(
            "Prueba 2",
            Actor.ARIEL);
        AgregarLinea(
            "Prueba 3",
            Actor.ARIEL);
    }

}
```

When I try to call to the function "AgregarLinea", the error jumps in. I tried instantiating in several ways, but I had no luck. Here is the rest of the relevant code:

```
public class Escena
{

    public var lineaActual:int;
    public var listaLineas:Vector.<Linea>;
    public var fondoEscena:Sprite;

    public function Escena() 
    {
        lineaActual = 0;
        listaLineas = new Vector.<Linea>();
    }

    //PRE:
    //POS: Se devuelve la lista correspondiente al momento actual
    public function ObtenerLinea():Linea {
        var ret:Linea=null;

        if (lineaActual < listaLineas.length) {
            ret = listaLineas[lineaActual];
            lineaActual++;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public function AgregarLinea(dialogo:String, actor:Actor = null, posActor:Point = null, gesto:String = "normal") {
        trace("Entro a AgregarLinea");
        listaLineas.push(new Linea(dialogo, actor, posActor, gesto));
        trace("Salgo de AgregarLinea");
    }


}
```

Not much mistery there. Parent class of "Prueba". The other classes are this two:

```
public class Actor extends MovieClip
{
    public var nombre:String;
    public var colorTexto:int = 0x000000;
    public var formatoTexto:TextFormat;

    public function Actor() {
        super();
    }

    //PRE: "gesto" es el nombre de etiqueta de alguno de los fotogramas del objeto
    //POS: Se cambia de fotograma al especificado
    public function CambiarGesto(gesto:String) {
        this.gotoAndStop(gesto);
    }

    //LISTA DE ACTORES DISPONIBLES
    public static var ARIEL:Actor = new Ariel();
    public static var NEREA:Actor = new Nerea();

}
```

and

```
public class Nerea extends Actor 
{

    public function Nerea() 
    {
        super();
        nombre = "Nerea";
    }

}
```

I don't know what the heck is wrong. It's quite a simple and direct code, but it says it can't be instantiated. There's some problem with the class Actor since the error surges from there:

```
at Actores::Actor$cinit()
at global$init()
at global$init()
```

Comment: Not completely sure after taking a quick look, but: in your first call to AgregarLInea you use 'new Nerea()' as an argument, instead of it's instance name: NEREA. Why?  Also you're leaving out 2 arguments, 'posActor' and 'gesto' when you make the call, but your AgregarLinea tries to push() those arguments.

Comment: The instance thing is a residual thing from testing. Originally I was calling it from it's instance name (didn't worked both ways); sorry about that.

About the push() thing, it's meant to pass default values defined in the function definition, so if I don't pass any value, it takes those instead.

Comment: What does your constructor in 'Actor' actually do?  Where do you call CambiarGesto ?

Comment: Your error states Actores::Actor$cinit() yet I do not see Actores package

Comment: you also left out the Linea class

Comment: Solved. Thanks The_asMan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure the issue is with the static vars and how it is instantiated.
try this.

```
public class Actor extends MovieClip
{
    public var nombre:String;
    public var colorTexto:int = 0x000000;
    public var formatoTexto:TextFormat;

    public function Actor() {
        super();
    }

    //PRE: "gesto" es el nombre de etiqueta de alguno de los fotogramas del objeto
    //POS: Se cambia de fotograma al especificado
    public function CambiarGesto(gesto:String) {
        this.gotoAndStop(gesto);
    }

    //LISTA DE ACTORES DISPONIBLES
    private static var _ARIEL:Actor;
    private static var _NEREA:Actor;


    public static function get ARIEL():Actor{
        if(!_ARIEL){
            _ARIEL = new Ariel();
        }
        return _ARIEL;
    }
    public static function get NEREA():Actor{
        if(!_NEREA){
            _NEREA= new Nerea();
        }
        return _NEREA;
    }
}
```